# Django - Create model object with Foreign Key object

Tags: python, django, serialization

I don't feel like I get an idea on how it should work...

I do have 2 models:
Group is my custom model I wanna save.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

User is a standard user model for the application. I'm skipping UserManager for now. Simply said User can have multiple groups.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()
```

A serializer for the custom model:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'subject', 'user')
```

And a viewset with overwritten `create` method:

```
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = group.objects.create(user=self.request.user)
        serializer = GroupSerializer(group)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When calling a POST a new `Group` is created. The `Group` has relation to the `User`, but other fields (name, subject) are empty.

On the other hand, when doing the request serialization, the `User` on the object is empty.

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = GroupSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How do I connect those 2 to make it work?

Comment: That makes sense, since you never use the `GroupSerializer` to *deserialize* the request, and thus add the details to the group.

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense since you never used the serializer to *deserialize* the request, and thus read the details passed in the POST request. You can work with:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = GroupSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
    else:
        # return response when the serializer rejects the input
        pass
    # return a response
    pass
```

In the serializer you mark the `user` field as `read_only`, to prevent the serializer from failing in case the `user` was not part of the request:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'subject', 'user')
        read_only_fields = ('user', )
```

Comment: It seems hacky to write to a field marked read_only and it should fail as user is not nullable.

Comment: @Melvyn: well it basically boils down to not validating this by the serializer. In the `serializer.save(..)` we then pass the user with `serializer.save(user=self.request.user)`

Comment: Yes, but I think the read_only is unnecessary. It should fail early, if you manage to remove user attribute from request - there's more than one thing going to go wrong then. Remember that in a correctly configured system,  request.user is there even when user is not logged in.

Comment: @Melvyn: yes, but that is the authorization you define at the view level. By not specifying the field as readonly, the serializer will fail, since it basically will wonder "where is the `user` field in the request". That would make a response "non-sensical, sine here the client is not supposed to include the user in the first place in the request. It is basically the same as a `ModelForm` where you include `user` as field. If the user then does not see a `user` field, then it is odd to get as as error that the user was not provided.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that...This is why I like Django's form approach of save(commit=False) better. You don't have these conflicting statements.